# React Native: Disabling scene transitions in NavigationExperimental

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-native, navigation

The reason, why I started using NavigationExperimental was to give me fuller control over navigation and rendering.

However, I am not able to find a way to remove the default animations on scene transitions. I just want to directly jump into the next screen.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  NavigationExperimental,
} from 'react-native';

const {
  CardStack: NavigationCardStack,
  StateUtils: NavigationStateUtils
} = NavigationExperimental;

class Navigation extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this._onPushRoute = this.props.onNavigationChange.bind(null, 'push');
    this._onPopRoute = this.props.onNavigationChange.bind(null, 'pop');

    this._renderScene = this._renderScene.bind(this);
  }

  // Now we finally get to use the `NavigationCardStack` to render the scenes.
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationCardStack
        onNavigateBack={this._onPopRoute}
        navigationState={this.props.navigationState}
        renderScene={(sceneProps) => {
          return this._renderScene(sceneProps);
        }}
        style={{flex:1}}
      />
    );
  }

  // Render a scene for route.
  // The detailed spec of `sceneProps` is defined at `NavigationTypeDefinition`
  // as type `NavigationSceneRendererProps`.
  // Here you could choose to render a different component for each route, but
  // we'll keep it simple.
  _renderScene(sceneProps) {
    return (
      <View
        route={sceneProps.scene.route}
        onPushRoute={this._onPushRoute}
        onPopRoute={this._onPopRoute}
        onExit={this.props.onExit}
        style={{flex:1}}
      >
        <sceneProps.component />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = Navigation
```

Answer (score 1):

Bad news transitions are harcoded in `CardStack`. There [PR](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/10251) had been provided but it was abandoned and wasn't merged. Good news `CardStack` is [js component](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/CustomComponents/NavigationExperimental/NavigationCardStack.js) so you can copy and modify it. Example of using `NavigationTransitioner` can be found in [UIExplorer](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/UIExplorer/js/NavigationExperimental).

**EDIT** Look like `cardStyleInterpolator` property was added 3 weeks ago and will be released in React Native 0.41. So you can just copy new version of `NavigationCardStack.js` file to you project and use it.